# r - find same times in n number of data frames

Tags: r, subset

Consider the following example:

```
Date1 = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-03 00:00"), 
            to = as.POSIXct("2010-06-20 23:00"), by = 120)
Dat1 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date1,
                   x1 = rnorm(length(Date1)))

Date2 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 03:30"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-07-03 22:00"), by = 120)
Dat2 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date2,
                   x1 = rnorm(length(Date2)))

Date3 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-06-08 01:30"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-07-13 11:00"), by = 120)
Dat3Matrix <- matrix(data = rnorm(length(Date3)*3), ncol = 3)

Dat3 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date3,
                   x1 = Dat3Matrix)

list1 <- list(Dat1,Dat2,Dat3)
```

Here I build three data.frames as an example and placed them all into a list. From here I would like to write a routine that would return the 3 data frames but only keeping the times that were present in each of the others i.e. all three data frames should be reduced to the times that were consistent among all of the data frames. How can this be done?

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity for `merge`. You could then split the resulting dataframe if you wanted them separate rather than as a single, multi-column dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zoo` has a multi-way merge.  This lapply's `read.zoo` over the components of `list1` converting them each to zoo class.  `tz=""` tells it to use POSIXct for the resulting date/times.  It then merges the converted components using `all=FALSE` so that only intersecting times are kept.

```
library(zoo)
z <- do.call("merge", c(lapply(setNames(list1, 1:3), read.zoo, tz = ""), all = FALSE))
```

If we later wish to convert `z` to data.frame try `dd <- cbind(Time = time(z), coredata(z))` but it might be better to keep it as a zoo object (or convert it to an xts object) so that further processing is simplified as well.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to find the respective indices and then subset accordingly:

```
idx1 <- (Dat1[,1] %in% Dat2[,1]) & (Dat1[,1] %in% Dat3[,1])
idx2 <- (Dat2[,1] %in% Dat1[,1]) & (Dat2[,1] %in% Dat3[,1])
idx3 <- (Dat3[,1] %in% Dat1[,1]) & (Dat3[,1] %in% Dat2[,1])
```

Now `Dat1[idx1,]`, `Dat2[idx2,]`, `Dat3[idx3,]` should give the desired result.

Comment: Or `%in% intersect(intersect(Dat1[,1],Dat2[,1]),Dat3[,1])`?

Comment: This seems rather long-winded if you had more than 3 data.frames though. It it possible to generate a function from this, where you would insert a list of the data frames and then apply these commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `merge`:

```
res <- NULL
for (i in 2:length(list1)) {
  dat <- list1[[i]]
  names(dat)[2] <- paste0(names(dat)[2], "_", i);
  dat[[paste0("id_", i)]] <- 1:nrow(dat)

  if (is.null(res)) {
    res <- dat
  } else {
    res <- merge(res, dat, by="DateTime")
  }
}
```

I added columns with id's; you could use these to index the records in the original data.frames