# find corresponding dateTime in several time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am an R newbie and am finding the conversion from matlab rather tricky, so apologies in advance for what could be a very simple question.

I am analyzing some time series data and the problem outlined below demonstrates the problem I am having in R:

```
Dat1 <- data.frame(dateTime = as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-03 00:00","2012-05-03 02:00",
                                           "2012-05-03 02:30","2012-05-03 05:00",
                                           "2012-05-03 07:00"), tz = 'UTC'),x1 = rnorm(5))
Dat2 <- data.frame(dateTime = as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-03 01:00","2012-05-03 01:30",
                                           "2012-05-03 02:30","2012-05-03 06:00",
                                           "2012-05-03 07:00"), tz = 'UTC'),x1 = rnorm(5))
Dat3 <- data.frame(dateTime = as.POSIXct(c("2012-05-03 00:15","2012-05-03 02:20",
                                           "2012-05-03 02:40","2012-05-03 06:25",
                                           "2012-05-03 07:00"), tz = 'UTC'),x1 = rnorm(5))
Dat4 <- data.frame(dateTime = as.POSIXct(c("2010-05-03 00:15","2010-05-03 02:20",
                                           "2010-05-03 02:40","2010-05-03 06:25",
                                           "2010-05-03 07:00"), tz = 'UTC'),x1 = rnorm(5))
```

So, here I have 5 data frames where all of the data are measured at similar times. I am now trying to ensure that all of the data frames have an identical time step i.e. all measured at the same time. I can do this for two data frames:

```
idx1 <- (Dat1[,1] %in% Dat2[,1])
```

which will tell me the index of the consistent times in these two data frames. I can then re-define the data frame by

```
newDat1 <- Dat1[idx1,]
```

to get the data desired.

My question now is, how do I apply this to all of the data frames i.e. more than 2. I have tried:

```
idx1 <- (Dat1[,1] %in% (Dat2[,1] %in% (Dat3[,1] %in% Dat4[,1])))
```

but I can see that this is completely wrong. Any suggestions? Please keep in mind that I have many data frames (more than five), where each contain different variables.

EDIT:

I may have found one way this can be done:

idx1 <- (Dat1[,1] %in% intersect(intersect(intersect(Dat1[,1],Dat2[,1]),Dat3[,1]),Dat4[,1]))

which will give the index, and can be used to define a new variable:

```
Dat1 <- Dat1[idx1,]
Dat2 <- Dat2[idx1,]
Dat3 <- Dat3[idx1,]
Dat4 <- Dat4[idx1,]
```

Although this work for this example, I was hoping to find a way of making this work for n number of data frames without having to write repeat this n number of times

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385909/r-find-same-times-in-n-number-of-data-frames/16387158#16387158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify timestamps that are common to all data frames, create a function to return the intersection of multiple vectors

```
intersectMulti <- function(x=list()){
 for(i in 2:length(x)){
    if(i==2) foo <- x[[i-1]]
    foo <- intersect(foo,x[[i]]) #find intersection between ith and previous
 }
 return(x[[1]][match(foo, x[[1]])]) #get original to retain format
}
```

Note that there are no common timestamps among the four dataframes in the question

```
> intersectMulti(x=list(Dat1[,1],Dat2[,1],Dat3[,1],Dat4[,1]))
character(0)
```

But there is one common timestamp in the first three dataframes

```
> intersectMulti(x=list(Dat1[,1],Dat2[,1],Dat3[,1]))
[1] "2012-05-03 07:00:00 UTC"
```

Use the result from the function to subset rows of each dataframe with common timestamp:

```
m <- intersectMulti(x=list(Dat1[,1],Dat2[,1],Dat3[,1]))

Dat1 <- Dat1[Dat1$dateTime %in% m,]
Dat2 <- Dat2[Dat2$dateTime %in% m,]
Dat3 <- Dat3[Dat3$dateTime %in% m,]
Dat4 <- Dat4[Dat4$dateTime %in% m,]

> Dat1
             dateTime         x1
5 2012-05-03 07:00:00 -0.1607363

> Dat2
        dateTime         x1
5 2012-05-03 07:00:00 -0.2662494

> Dat3
             dateTime         x1
5 2012-05-03 07:00:00 -0.1917905
```

Comment: The overall aim here is to alter the data frames that are already defines i.e. alter Dat1, Dat2, Dat3, Dat4 to have the rows which correspond to the index you have shown. It is not clear to my how this could be achieved.

Comment: I edited above to subset the matching rows from each dataframe.  is this what you wanted?  To return index for each Dat, simply use `match(m, Dat1$dateTime)` instead of subset.

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you:

```
idx1 <- (Dat1[,1] %in% intersect(intersect(intersect(Dat1[,1],Dat2[,1]),Dat3[,1]),Dat4[,1]))
```

then try this, it works on lists/vectors and more elegant:

```
idx1 <- Dat1[,1] %in% Reduce(intersect, list(Dat1[,1], Dat2[,1], Dat3[,1], Dat4[,1]))
```